# Replace newlines and XML tags with ','

Tags: python, xml, regex

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
  <file>
    <name>NAME_OF_FILE</name>
  </file>
  <file>
    <name>NAME_OF_FILE</name>
  </file>
```

I’m trying to write a Python script that will replace all newlines, tags and whitespace *between tags* (i.e. not the elements themselves) with ','.

The output for the file above should look like this:

```
NAME_OF_FILE','NAME_OF_FILE','NAME_OF_FILE','
```

Here's what I've got so far. I'm having trouble understanding exactly how Python handles newlines:

```
import sys
import os
import re

source = r'c:\A\grepper.txt'

f = open(source,'r')
out = open(r'c:\A\bout.txt', 'a')

for line in f:
    one = re.sub(r"\n", '', line)
    two = re.sub(r"\r", '', one)
    three = re.sub(r'</name>.*<name>', '\',\'', two)
    out.write(three)

out.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `r`s, as they quote the string literally.

```
one = re.sub("\n", '', line)
two = re.sub("\r", '', one)
```

You can also use `string.replace()` for these simple replacements, as well as combine them into one line.

```
line = re.sub('r</name>.*<name>', "','", line.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', ''))
out.write(line)
```

However, that still doesn't solve the problem of getting your desired output. I'd suggest doing the following for that:

```
results = []
for line in f:
    match = re.search(r'<name>(.*)</name>', line)
    if match:
        results.append(match.group(1))
print >>out, "','".join(results)
```

Here's it working: http://ideone.com/ik48G

Comment: awesome. Just a small typo: ','.join should be "','".join. +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing you might want to consider matching what you want:

```
tag_re = re.compile('''
    <(?P<tag>[a-z]+)> # First match the tag, must be a-z enclosed in <>
    (?P<value>[^<>]+) # Match the value, anything but <>
    </(?P=tag)> # Match the same tag we got earlier, but the closing version
''', re.VERBOSE)
print "','".join(m.group('value') for m in tag_re.finditer(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are wrong for this.  Use the `xml.sax.handler` module.

Untested:

```
import xml.sax
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class CharactersOnlyContentHandler(ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        ContentHandler.__init__(self)
        self.text = ""
        self.texts = []

    def characters(self, content):
        self.text += content

    def endElement(self, name):
        if self.text:
            self.texts.append(self.text)
            self.text = ""

handler = CharactersOnlyContentHandler()
xml.sax.parse(xml_file_name, handler)
print ",".join("'%s'" % s for s in handler.texts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import lxml.etree

myxml = """
<filelist>
    <file>
        <name>FIRST FILE NAME</name>
    </file>
    <file>
        <name>SECOND FILE NAME</name>
    </file>
</filelist>
"""

root = lxml.etree.fromstring(myxml)
filenames = root.xpath('//file/name/text()')
print ', '.join(filenames)
```

results in

```
FIRST FILE NAME, SECOND FILE NAME
```